# A fair die is tossed until the sequence “44” is seen. Let N be the number of tosses this requires. Find E $N$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

A fair die is tossed until the sequence “44” is seen. Let $N$ be the number of tosses this requires. Find $E[N]$.

---

I have my own solution which I need someone to verify. And this problem has to be solved with the property $E[N]$ = $E \left[E[N|X]\right]$. Below is my solution:

---

Let $X$ be a random variable such that 
$$
   X = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 &, \text{getting a "4" after a "4" }\\
       0 &, \text{not getting a "4" after a "4"}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$
And
\begin{align}
E[N]
&= E \left[E[N|X]\right]\\
&= E[N|X=1]P[X=1]+E[N|X=0]P[X=0]\\
\end{align}
For $E[N|X=1]$, since we condition on getting the first "4", we know that once we get the first "4", the next roll will be a "4" as well. Therefore, we only need to care how many rolls we need to get the first "4" in this situation. And this becomes a "geometric distribution". A geometric random variable has a expectation of $\frac{1}{p}$, in this case, $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{6}}=6.$ And adding the next roll on which we will get the next "4", $E[N|X=1]=6+1=7.$

For $E[N|X=0],$  let random variable $\tilde{N}$ denote the number of tosses required to get sequence "44" after getting a first "4", given that the next roll is not a "4". Since the expected value of getting the first "4" is 6, $E[N|X=0]=E[6+\tilde{N}]=6+E[\tilde{N}].$ And it is not hard to see that $E[N]=E[\tilde{N}]$ since both scenarios need to get the "44" sequence and each roll is independent.

To sum up:
\begin{align}
E[N]
&= E \left[E[N|X]\right]\\
&= E[N|X=1]P[X=1]+E[N|X=0]P[X=0]\\
&= 7P[X=1]+\left[6+E[\tilde{N}]\right]P[X=0]\\
&= 7\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left[6+E[\tilde{N}]\right]\cdot\frac{5}{6}\\
&= \frac{7}{6}+5+\frac{5}{6}E[\tilde{N}]\\
E[N]
&= \frac{7}{6}+5+\frac{5}{6}E[N]\\
\frac{1}{6}E[N]
&=\frac{37}{6}\\
E[N]
&=37
\end{align}

---

I have typed this for so long and any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And it is not hard to see that $E[N]=E[\tilde{N}]$...

Actually i is not hard to see that $E[\tilde{N}]=E[1+N]$ since, when evaluating $\tilde N$, one assumes that the first toss after getting a first "4" is not a "4" hence one needs a supplementary toss when compared to $N$.

After that, everything flows smoothly and one gets $E[N]=42$.

Comment: Yet another empirical confirmation that mistakes have a natural tendency to hide under statements like "it is not hard to see that" or "and it is obvious that"... :-)

Comment: WoW, it is amazing that you caught the error in such a short time. I don't think I would ever notice that myself. Thanks!

Comment: And do you see another way to do this that's less error-prone?

Comment: This is the correct approach. That you made a mistake in a specific step when implementing it is no reason to abandon it.